# Replace column value substring with hash of substring in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column containing a description including customer ids which I need to replace with their `sha2` hashed version.

Example: the column value `"X customer 0013120109 in country AU.` should be turned into `"X customer d8e824e6a2d5b32830c93ee0ca690ac6cb976cc51706b1a856cd1a95826bebd in country AU.`

MRE:

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sha2, regexp_replace, lit, concat
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType

data = [
    [1, "Sold device 11312."],
    [2, "X customer 0013120109 in country AU."],
    [3, "Y customer 0013140033 in country BR."],
]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(name="Id", dataType=LongType()),
        StructField(name="Description", dataType=StringType())
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

My attempted solution was to use `regexp_replace` in combination with `regexp_extract`, but it expects a concrete string as "replacement" value - while my replacement value would be dynamic.

```
df = (
     df
     .withColumn("Description", regexp_replace("Description",
                                               r"customer \d+",
                                               concat(lit("customer "), 
                                                      sha2(regexp_extract(
                                                              "Description",
                                                              r".* customer (\d+) .*",
                                                              1),
                                                           256
                                                           )
                                                      )
                                               )
                )
        )
```

PS: I really want to avoid UDFs since the transformation from JVM to Python and back is a huge performance degradation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution using a combination of `concat`, `substr` and `expr`:

```
df = (
df
.withColumn("regexp_extract",
            regexp_extract('Description', '.* customer (\\d+) .*', 1)
            )
.withColumn("NewColumn",
            when(expr("length(regexp_extract)") > lit(1),
                 # Concatenate the substrings: [before_id, hashed_id, after_id]
                 concat(
                     # From the start of the column until the index of the extract.
                     col("Description").substr(lit(0), expr("instr(Description, regexp_extract)") - lit(1)),
                     # Hashed extract
                     sha2(regexp_extract('Description', '.* customer (\\d+) .*', 1), 256),
                     # Subtr from (Index extract + length of the extract) until the end of the Column.
                     col("Description").substr(expr("instr(Description, regexp_extract)") +
                                               expr("length(regexp_extract)"), expr("length(Description)"))
                 )
                 ).otherwise(col("Description"))
            )
.drop("regexp_extract")

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

- Approach is quite simple, split the string into 3 parts:

1. One with anything before the customer id
2. customer id
3. Anything after customer id.

- Then mask the customer id, and concat all 3 of them.

Code:

```
 df_final = df .withColumn("regexp_extract1",
                when(regexp_extract('Description', '^(.* customer) (\\d+)(.*)$', 1) != '',
                     regexp_extract('Description', '^(.* customer) (\\d+)(.*)$', 1))\
                     .otherwise(col('Description')))\
 .withColumn("regexp_extract2", regexp_extract('Description', '^(.* customer) (\\d+)(.*)$', 2))\
 .withColumn("regexp_extract3", regexp_extract('Description', '^(.* customer) (\\d+)(.*)$', 3))\
 .withColumn("extract2_sha2",when(col('regexp_extract2')!='',sha2("regexp_extract2",256)).otherwise(''))\
 .withColumn('Masked Description',F.concat(col('regexp_extract1'),lit(' '),col('extract2_sha2'),col('regexp_extract3')))\
 .drop(*['regexp_extract1','regexp_extract2','regexp_extract3','extract2_sha2'])

df_final.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Id |Description                         |Masked Description                                                                        |
+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |Sold device 11312.                  |Sold device 11312.                                                                        |
|2  |X customer 0013120109 in country AU.|X customer d8e824e6a2d5b32830c93ee0ca690ac6cb976cc51706b1a856cd1a95826bebdb in country AU.|
|3  |Y customer 0013140033 in country BR.|Y customer 2f4ab0aeb1f3332b8b9ccdd3a9fca759f267074e6621e5362acdd6f22211f167 in country BR.|
+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]